# Julia MethodError: no method matching

Tags: julia

I am running the folowing code:

```
function P_diastole(P0,t,R,C)
    t0 = t[1];
    P_diastole = P0*exp((-(t.-t0))./(R*C))
    return P_diastole
end

t = 0:0.1:5;
P0 = 80;
R = 700;
C = 2.56;

P = P_diastole(P0,t,R,C);
```

But am getting the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching exp(::StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64})

Closest candidates are:
  exp(!Matched::Union{Float16, Float32, Float64})
   @ Base special\exp.jl:325
  exp(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{T, <:AbstractMatrix} where T)
   @ LinearAlgebra C:\Users\aoife\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:595
  exp(!Matched::LinearAlgebra.Transpose{T, <:AbstractMatrix} where T)
   @ LinearAlgebra C:\Users\aoife\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\share\julia\stdlib\v1.9\LinearAlgebra\src\dense.jl:596
  ...


Stacktrace:
 [1] P_diastole(P0::Int64, t::StepRangeLen{Float64, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Base.TwicePrecision{Float64}, Int64}, R::Int64, C::Float64)
   @ Main c:\Users\aoife\Desktop\School\5 yr\Thesis\Julia\Windkessel.ipynb:3
 [2] top-level scope
   @ c:\Users\aoife\Desktop\School\5 yr\Thesis\Julia\Windkessel.ipynb:6
```

Any idea what the issue is?

When I initially got the error, I hadn't included the . before the - and the / in the P_diastole = P0*exp((-(t.-t0))./(R*C)) line. However, fixing this hasn't gotten rid of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look at the error, it says that it cannot find the `exp` method for `StepRangeLen`. That means that inside `exp` you put something else than you wanted to. This comes actually from your definition of `t` - the way you write it, it creates a range object (`StepRangeLen`). So you need to convert it to a vector first:

```
t = collect(0:0.1:5);
```

If you try running it then, you notice that `exp` cannot be called on a vector, so you need a dot there as well. So the correct version would be:

```
function P_diastole(P0,t,R,C)
  t0 = t[1];
  P_diastole = P0*exp.((-(t.-t0))./(R*C))
  return P_diastole
end

t = collect(0:0.1:5);
P0 = 80;
R = 700;
C = 2.56;

P = P_diastole(P0,t,R,C)
```

Comment: Good answer. Another way to write that line would be `P_diastole = @. P0 * exp((-(t-t0))/(R*C))`. The `@.` macro adds the `.`operator to every call that comes after it, and makes things slightly more convenient and readable.

Comment: Great tip! I'm still new to JuliaLang, so I didn't know about this one

Comment: The second part of your answer is fine, the first part might give performance sensitive Julia users heart palpitations - a good rule of thumb in Julia is "never use `collect` ever" as most of the time it needlessly allocates an extra vector when you could have worked directly on whatever object you had before `collect`ing. This is a case in point: `exp.(1:0.1:5)` works just fine, and doing `exp.(collect(1:0.1:5))` just doubles the allocations for no benefit.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I didn't check `exp.` first.

Comment: Great thank you!